# Использование PreferenceActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

Для настроек использую `PreferenceActivity`, на метод `addPreferencesFromResource()`; эклипс говорит, что он устарел и нужно использовать `fragment`. Что и в каком случае лучше использовать? Можно ли продолжать пользоваться `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: Некак не могу понять, причем фрагменты к преференсАктивити?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно указанный метод объявлен устаревшим, начиная с API Level 11 - то есть с Android 3.0. Одновременно объявлены устаревшими методы создания диалогов типа `Activity.showDialog()`, вместо них рекомендовано пользоваться [фрагментами](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Но есть несколько существенных ремарок:

1. [Deprecation не означает](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/deprecation/deprecation.html), что методы не будут работать - это означает, что методы заменены на другие более новые/устойчивые/лучшие. И, возможно, в будущем они не будут работать.
2. Большинство Android устройств по прежнему работает на API Level <= 10, соответственно, я бы предпочел спокойно продолжать использовать методы устаревшие с API 10.

Используйте для сборки SDK Level 10 и IDE не будет ругаться на устаревание.

Если все таки неймется и вам охота использовать SDK для ICS то тогда [пример использования PreferenceFragment здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html)

Comment: @Barmaley, вам не кажется, что 1-й и 2-й пункт противоречат друг другу? Не надо использовать устаревшие методы. Есть ведь библиотека, позволяющая охватить весь набор ныне существующих версий SDK. Да, она будет работать медленнее, но вряд ли кто-нибудь надумает писать сервер на дроиде.

Comment: @RomanoO, а где ты тут противоречие собственно нашел? В чем?

Comment: Нет не противоречат.  Зачем писать под Gingerbread на API для ICS? Нужна разумная консервативность, я лично предпочитаю всегда писать под API на шаг/уровень меньше самой распоследней.

Comment: Это логично, однако возьмут разработчики дроида и скажут: API <10 в android 5.0 больше не поддерживается. И что, вы будете все свои приложения переписывать? Не прсто же так был выпущен этот пакет поддержки.

Comment: Вероятность ровно такая же как и то, что в Android 6.0 скажут что API < 14 более не поддерживается. Так не будет, иначе весь backward compatibility полетит и обрушится нафик весь рынок Android приложений. Google я думаю это понимают. Возьмите методы класса `java.util.Date` - половина из них уже депрекирована сто лет назад, но поддержка все равно есть во всех версиях Java

Comment: И тем не менее, разработчики рекомендуют использовать фрагменты. Не понимаю, зачем использовать устаревшие методы, когда есть новые, реализующие весь функционал старых, но делающие это лучше? Тем более, для новых разработок.

Comment: Вопрос находится не в этой плоскости, а в плоскости какой SDK использовать? SDK 14 - для ICS или SDK 10-й для Gingerbread? Если использовать 14-й SDK то надо использовать фрагменты, если для Gingerbread то все делать по старому.

Answer (score 2):

[В блоге Дарьи Ряжских](http://megadarja.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-5.html) есть такая статья, посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

Фрагменты надо использовать. Для версий Android < 3.0 есть [пакет поддержки](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676223/about-working-with-fragment-in-android-2-1-updated).

Comment: Дай какой-нибудь простенький пример, как их использовать!

Comment: Гугл - android fragments exapmle